Windows found problems with the file system that could not be corrected?
I have a NTFS formatted USB drive that I use both with Linux and Windows 11 and it normally works OK. Recently Linux gave me a rather dire sounding error:
zog@kb:~$ sudo mount /dev/sdc2 ~/Templates/
[sudo] password for zog: 
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.

So I hooked it up to my Windows box, ran `chkdsk as admin and got:
The type of the file system is NTFS.
Volume label is USBDRV.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...
  259456 file records processed.
File verification completed.
 Phase duration (File record verification): 3.46 minutes.
  1069 large file records processed.
 Phase duration (Orphan file record recovery): 4.10 milliseconds.
  0 bad file records processed.
 Phase duration (Bad file record checking): 1.42 milliseconds.

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...
  18 reparse records processed.
Correcting error in index $I30 for file 72F9.
Failed to correct errors in index $I30 of file 72F9.
  279010 index entries processed.
Index verification completed.
 Phase duration (Index verification): 6.38 minutes.
  0 unindexed files scanned.
 Phase duration (Orphan reconnection): 64.95 milliseconds.
  0 unindexed files recovered to lost and found.
 Phase duration (Orphan recovery to lost and found): 4.69 milliseconds.
  18 reparse records processed.
 Phase duration (Reparse point and Object ID verification): 4.64 milliseconds.

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.
 Phase duration (Security descriptor verification): 106.32 milliseconds.
  9778 data files processed.
 Phase duration (Data attribute verification): 1.01 milliseconds.
CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Usn Journal verification completed.

Windows found problems with the file system that could not be corrected.

  16777199 MB total disk space.
1789432760 KB in 230370 files.
     55860 KB in 9779 indexes.
         0 KB in bad sectors.
    853031 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
  15028819 MB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
4294963194 total allocation units on disk.
3847377782 allocation units available on disk.
Total duration: 9.85 minutes (591124 ms).

So, assuming I'm reading this correctly, there's one file that's causing this problem? If yes how can I find and delete it or resolve the issue? (I am hoping there is a way as I do not have enough storage to copy stuff off this onto something else...).
It's an old Drobo so considering its age I've made sure the data on there isn't something I will be crying about if it dies but it would be better of course to not lose it. That said, how can one check smart stats of drives that are in a raid array?

Your drive is failing and about to fail completely. You should backup ASAP and retire it.

Please add to your post the SMART attributes for the disk, to verify its health. In the meantime, better backup your data.

"So, assuming i am reading this right there is one file that's causing this problem?" - Yes; "If yes how can i find and delete it or resolve the issue?" - The file is already gone or otherwise inaccessible. I would also agree your drive is starting to fail. I assume you ran chkdsk /f twice and rebooted Windows between each attempt

Note that you may be wasting the last gasps of the disk's life trying to fix it rather than trying to back up your content (I've done that before and it sucks). check your smart stats and if they are indicating health issues, focus on recovering your data to other media instead. am i reading it correctly that this is a 20TB disk (16.7TB usable)?

@FrankThomas - 1789432760KB is ~1.7TB and 15028819MB is 15TB so your math holds up

ok, a small (big) detail that i did not mention, its an old drobo so considering its age I've made sure the data on there isn't something I will be crying about if it dies BUT it would be better of course to not lose it. That said, how can one check smart stats of drives that are in a raid array? (sorry I know of smart but not much else).

so that the disks are part of an array won't affect SMART at all, but it may make it hard to see the stats. if Drobo has a management interface it will probably be able to tell you about disk health, but if not, you can power off the array, remove each disk one at a time (while leaving it off, and carefully labeling the disk so you remember where it goes) and put it into another system to check the stats. its a pain but doable. just make sure no changes are made to the disk while its in that state. don't turn the array back on until all disks are returned to their original slot.

@DrZog - "how can one check smart stats of drives that are in a raid array?" - You can't; Some of S.M.A.R.T data is exposed through the Drobo management software. Health of individual disks are going to be tough to determine.  However, a single disk is unlikely to the problem, since Drobo uses Beyond RAID which was their own RAID implementation.

Just to turn the several commenting answers into one actual answer: Your drive is failing and should be backed up and retired.
The "one file" is just where the current evidence of corruption/failure exists on the drive. It isn't a "stuck" file, but the files record corresponds to where the corruption on the drive is.
So, the error messages are telling you something, but not necessarily what the words on the screen would typically mean.
